# Multiple strings in for loop grep -wc

Tags: bash, for-loop, grep

How do I add multiple strings to search the same file for:

Currently:

```
#!/bin/bash

for log in filename.log.201[45]-*-*.gz; do
    printf '%s:' "$log"
    zcat "$log" | grep -wc 'dollar for dollars'
done
```

Desired result:

```
#!/bin/bash

for log in filename.log.201[45]-*-*.gz; do
    printf '%s:' "$log"
    echo "count for dollar for dollars"
    zcat "$log" | grep -wc 'dollar for dollars'

    echo "count for pollar for pollars"
    zcat "$log" | grep -wc 'pollar for pollars'
done
```

Comment: Why not run your **Desired result** script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested loop for this one.

```
for count in 'dollar for dollars' 'pollar for pollars'; do 
 for log in filename.log.201[45]-*-*.gz; do
     printf '%s:' "$log"
     echo -n $count : 
     zcat "$log" | grep -wc "$count"
  done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably would be better off using an actual programming language, like `awk`.

If you want a count of the total number of occurrences of each pattern (which might be more than the number of lines in which each pattern appears, in the case that a pattern appears more than once in a line) you could use the `-o` option to grep to output the actual matches, and then construct the final report using `sort | uniq -c`, which counts the number of occurrences of each unique line in an output stream. That lets you supply multiple patterns to a single grep command, using the `-e` option:

```
for log in filename.log.201[45]-*-*.gz; do
  zcat "$log" |
  grep -e "pattern 1" -e "pattern 2" -ow |
  sort | uniq -c |
  xargs -d\\n printf "${log//%/%%}:%s\n"
done
```